# Coils on an iron bar question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, magnetic-fields

I have this question, asking me to determine the direction the ammeter will flick when the switch located at S is closed. I used the right hand rule to work out the position of the north and south pole, as shown on the left hand side of the diagram, I then realized that a south pole must be induced on the left of the right hand side coil to conserve energy and a north on the far right meaning I could apply the right hand rule to get the current direction hence the ammeter flick direction. I have the right answer accordingly but is this reasoning I have used correct?
[image]

Comment: Correct, this is basically [Lenz's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenz%27s_law)

Comment: @caverac May I also ask, if the variable resistor were to be suddenly increased, this would reduce the magnetic field strength due to a smaller current (as if a magnet were to be moving away from the coil Q) meaning a current would flow to the right instead in coil Q (Again Lenz's law)?

Comment: Right, since the polarity of the right coil switches